# regex, space between works only

Tags: javascript, regex

I want match a whole string about words with spaces in the middle only

I have this:

```
/^[\ba-zA-Z]+$/.test(this.value)
```

I want it to return true for if it has no empty words with no spaces at the ends, only account for alphabets and has length of at least 1.

however, the above returns false for "asdf asd", it returns false if it sees any space

Comment: does it need to be regex? this can easily be done with string functions

Comment: What's an empty word?

Comment: I don't understand the question, but you seem to have 2 misunderstandings about word-boundary/`\b`: (1) Word boundary is a zero-width assertion (matches a substring of length 0, not a character). So `/.\b./` matches `"a-"` and `"-a"` (but not `"aa"` or `"--"`). (2) Character classes match single characters (not zero-width assertions), so `\b` inside a character class isn't a word boundary. It's an alert/bell character (see ASCII table). PS: There's nothing wrong with using space characters in a character class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this pattern:

```
/^[a-zA-Z]+( [a-zA-Z]+)*$/
```

This will match any sequence words (of Latin letters) separated by a single space, but with no spaces on the end.

You can also simplify this a little bit by using the `i` flag for case insensitive matching:

```
/^[a-z]+( [a-z]+)*$/i
```

Comment: @user2580016 Your solution didn't work because inside of a character class `\b` actually refers to the *backspace* character--one of the original [ASCII control characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_control_characters). So your pattern would match any sequence of Latin letters or backspace characters.

Comment: how i can I add minimum and maximum char retriction to this regex? {3,20}

Comment: @peterkr You can use a lookahead. For example `/^(?=.{3,20}$)[a-z]+( [a-z]+)*$/i` will match any string as described above, but only if it between 3 and 20 characters long, inclusive.